# How can I build a dynamic "ADD/Remove" diagram using asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing some R&D regarding the following buisness requirment:-

I have a model in razor view containing customer info , so how can i build a web "Add/Remove" diagram to insert and remove customers, something similar to the following image:-

[soumya.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/image3.png](http://soumya.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/image3.png)

Comment: could you be more specific with what you are having difficulty?

Comment: i need some tutorials or documentation on how to implement such a requirment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's quite easy.

You need to use two list elements where you store data "on the model" and "out of the model". On client code you manage the movement of data between both elements and, on form submission you just need to send to the server the data that's contained "on the model" side.

Then, on the server you delete all data that's not on the list you passed to your controller and add those data that's on the list but it isn't on your business model instance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into something to do client side data manipulation.  The current framework of choice in the Microsoft camp is Knockout.js. You will need to display the data from the server, allow the client to manipulate it in javascript, and save the data back to the server.  Ryan Niemeyer has a bunch of examples using knockoutjs on his side, [knockmeout.net](http://knockmeout.net), and the example [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html) is pretty close to what you are talking about.